# Click once desktop application and roaming profiles

Tags: c#, clickonce, roaming-profile

I hope someone can help me.  I'm working on a desktop application, which uses the click once install and update logic.

We've been using it for some time now without issues, but some of our clients are now  using roaming profiles and this seems to remove the installation, on log off. This means our clients need to download and install the application each time they log back onto the PC.

Has anyone had this issue and more important got a work around?

Thanks

Comment: [Microsoft ClickOnce deployment is not supported with Roaming Profiles.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2571899/microsoft-clickonce-deployment-is-not-supported-with-roaming-profiles) - _"ClickOnce deployment is not supported when using Roaming User Profiles. While variations may sometime work such configurations are not tested. Such scenarios could be adversely affected by future product updates. Therefore ClickOnce is not supported when using any variation of the Roaming Profiles."_

Comment: Thanks Stuart. We have found a way to resolve it to a number of clients by changing a group policy. There are a number of clients that this doesn't fix this issue.  I was wondering if there could be anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know now, officially Click once does not support, but there is always a way around.
I have create a simple application that works around this issue.

http://coopsblog.wales/Blog/ViewBlog/User-roaming-profile-ClickOnce-application-restore

Comment: This is the new link in case anyone needs it:
https://dev.to/chriscooper01/user-roaming-profile-clickonce-application-restore-2io1